# jQuery operations on function that lies outside $(document).ready();

Tags: jquery

I had to move my function, say myFunction, that would be called on click of a `<a>` tag outside `$(document).ready()`. Now how do I use `$(someId).css('display','none')` and similar operations on click of this function?

I do not want to use `$(a tag's id).click(function() {})` inside `$document.ready()` as I have to pass several values from html to javaScript using `myFunction(value1, value2, value3....)`.

Comment: Please show us your real code.  Otherwise, a binding outside of a document ready is not guarenteed to find the elements, if the script runs before the elements exist on the page.

Comment: It's also unclear how `$().click()` relates to calling `myFunction()` with what you have given.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. That being said, in short you need to execute your JS code after the elements you're referencing have been created within it. The most common ways to do that you can either use the `document.ready` handler, or places your logic at the end of the `body`

Comment: HTML:
`<a href="#" onClick='myFunction(value1, value2, value3);'> Link </a>`

JS:
`$(document).ready(function($){ .... });`
`function myFunction() { //I am unable to use $ here and it gives me a TypeError. I wanna do something like $(id).css(style,value);   }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that holds those other operations. Then reference / call the function.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function({  
//My Code

otherFunction();

});
```